# What is React native's "JSTimers.callTimers"?

Tags: react-native, message-queue, react-native-bridge

I'm debugging the react-native bridge to see conversations between native & JS side.

As I can see so many messages were sent via the bridge even I didn't touch anything, it's a non-stop conversation.

[image]

> method: "callTimers"
> module: "JSTimers"
> type: 0
>
> args: (4) [(...), (...), (...), (...)]
> method: "createTimer"
> module: "Timing"
> type: 1
>
> args: [(...)]
> method: "deleteTimer"
> module: "Timing"
> type: 1

Can anyone explain this issue to me?

Here how I inspect the bridge messages:

```js
  import MessageQueue from 'react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue';

  MessageQueue.spy((msg) => {
      const fromTo = msg.type === 0 ? '[To JS]' : '[To Native]';
      const color = msg.type === 0 ? '#693' : '#639';
      console.log('%c' + fromTo + ' args, msg:', 'color: ' + color, msg.args, msg)
  })
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I see dozens of these calls: `N->JS : JSTimers.callTimers([[6361]])` each second

Comment: I ignored it for a while, I guess there was a ticker(timeout/interval/animation) 
 running somewhere inside my app, haven't tried with a blank app yet.